# unit test for service with a promise

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a service that i wrote for a project i am currently working on and i am trying to write a unit test for it. Below is the code for the service

```
angular.module('services').factory('Authorization', ['$q', 'Refs', function($q, Refs) {

  function isAuthorized() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var authData = Refs.rootRef.getAuth();
    var adminRef;

    if(authData.google) {
      adminRef = Refs.rootRef.child('admins').child(authData.uid);
    } else {
      adminRef = Refs.rootRef.child('admins').child(authData.auth.uid);
    }

    adminRef.on('value', function(adminSnap) {
      deferred.resolve(adminSnap.val());
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return {
    isAuthorized: isAuthorized
  };
}]);
```

I have written a unit test for it but anytime i run the test i get this error message ' Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.'

Below is the code for the unit test i wrote for the service:

```
'use strict';

describe('Authorization Service', function() {

  var Refs, $q, Authorization, authData, scope, deferred;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('Sidetime'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_Refs_, $rootScope, _$q_, _Authorization_) {
    Refs = _Refs_;
    $q = _$q_;
    Authorization = _Authorization_;
  }));

  iit('return admin object', function(done) {
    var result;

    Authorization.isAuthorized = function() {
      deferred = $q.defer();
      authData = {google: 'uid:112222'};

      if(authData.google) {
        deferred.resolve(authData);
      }

      return deferred.promise;
    };

    Authorization.isAuthorized().then(function(result) { 
      console.log('result', result);
      expect(result).toEqual(authData);
      //done();
    });
  });
});
```

I am not sure I am writing the unit test properly. I will appreciate if someone could show be a better way of writing the unit test for this service. Thanks for your anticipated assistance.

Comment: iit('return admin object', function(done) {
  ?

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan i tried putting done and the test times out everytime

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working plunkr, with slight modifications as I don't have the code to all of your dependencies:

```
 angular.module('services', []).factory('Authorization', ['$q', function($q) {

  function isAuthorized() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    deferred.resolve({authData: {google: 'uid: 1122222'}});
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return {
    isAuthorized: isAuthorized
  };
}]);


describe('Authorization Service', function() {

  var  $q, Authorization, scope, deferred;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('services'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$q_, _Authorization_) {
    $q = _$q_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    Authorization = _Authorization_;

    Authorization.isAuthorized = function() {
      deferred = $q.defer();
      authData = {google: 'uid:112222'};

      if(authData.google) {
        deferred.resolve(authData);
      }

      return deferred.promise;
    };
  }));

  it('return admin object', function(done) {
    var result;

    var promise = Authorization.isAuthorized();

    promise.then(function(result) {
      expect(result).toEqual(authData);
      expect(result.google).toEqual('uid:112222e');
    });

    deferred.resolve(result);
    scope.$digest();


  });
});



(function() {
  var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
  jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 250;

  /**
   Create the `HTMLReporter`, which Jasmine calls to provide results of each spec and each suite. The Reporter is responsible for presenting results to the user.
   */
  var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter();
  jasmineEnv.addReporter(htmlReporter);

  /**
   Delegate filtering of specs to the reporter. Allows for clicking on single suites or specs in the results to only run a subset of the suite.
   */
  jasmineEnv.specFilter = function(spec) {
    return htmlReporter.specFilter(spec);
  };

  /**
   Run all of the tests when the page finishes loading - and make sure to run any previous `onload` handler

   ### Test Results

   Scroll down to see the results of all of these specs.
   */
  var currentWindowOnload = window.onload;
  window.onload = function() {
    if (currentWindowOnload) {
      currentWindowOnload();
    }

    //document.querySelector('.version').innerHTML = jasmineEnv.versionString();
    execJasmine();
  };

  function execJasmine() {
    jasmineEnv.execute();
  }
})();
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DCrr6pVzF9D4OuayCZU7?p=preview

Comment: @Ed Cottrell Your plunkr solution doesn't work. if you change the expect to not.toEqual(authData) it still passes. The console.log isn't even logging anything and that is the major problem i am having. If i call done(), the test fails and timesout

Comment: It's not my solution; I just fixed the formatting (that's why my name appears under "edited..."). It's @Cognitronic's solution.

Comment: @Cognitronic Your plunkr solution doesn't work. if you change the expect to not.toEqual(authData) it still passes. The console.log isn't even logging anything and that is the major problem i am having. If i call done(), the test fails and timesout

Comment: @user3775998 Sorry about that - check it now.  The second expect fails due to the 'e' at the end of the toEqual statement.  If you remove the 'e' you'll see that the test is now passing.  Note that I had to execute scope.$digest() to manually kick of the digest cycle and get the promise to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

> Take a look over at [spies in jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) to get a deeper introduction

I've taken Cognitroics plunkr and modified it in the way I usually write my test. Take a look at it here http://plnkr.co/edit/W5pP82CKj7tc6IO3Wj9S?p=preview

But basically what you should do is utilizing the awesomeness of spies in jasmine.

Here's how it looks like.

```
describe('My aweomse test suite', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        module('Awesome');
        inject(function($injector){
           this.MyService = $injector.get('MyService');
           this.$q = $injector.get('$q');
           this.$scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();

           spyOn(this.MyService, 'someMethod').andCallFake(function(){
              var defer = this.$q.defer();
              defer.resolve();
              return defer.promise;
           });
        });

        it('should do seomthing', function(){
            // given
            var result;

            // when
            this.MyServcie.someMethod().then(function(){
                result = 'as promised';
            });

            this.$scope.$digest();

            // then
            expect(result).toEqual('as promised');
        });
    });
});
```